# NSIS scripts-Changing header text. Also using same variable in both installer and uninstaller section

Tags: text, header, installation, customization, nsis

I am writing an installer using NSIS. I wanna know how to change or write a description(text on white header)on custom pages? For eg: I am inserting a customized page after the directory page and the description remains the same i.e Choose Install Location...
But I wanna change it according to my page requirement. How should I change this text?
Also I wanna access a variable in uninstaller section which is set with some string in installer section. Please help me on this...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, you seem to have two questions there.. probably best to post them separately :)

For setting the title of the customized page, simply use the following macro (I've got mine placed just prior to calling `nsDialogs::Create`)

```
!insertmacro MUI_HEADER_TEXT $(MY_CUSTOM_TITLE) $(MY_CUSTOM_SUBTITLE)
```

Where `MY_CUSTOM_TITLE` and `MY_CUSTOM_SUBTITLE` are variables set elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to save the string value of the variable during installation by writing it out to a file or registry setting, and then later during uninstallation reading that value from the same location.

I think you need to do this:

```
!define MUI_DIRECTORYPAGE_TEXT_DESTINATION "My alternate Choose Install Location text"
```

You could also edit the language files.  This is assuming you are using MUI for your custom pages:
http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Modern%20UI/Readme.html

Comment: Unfortunately, for uninstaller there are barely any custom texts (only MUI_UNCONFIRMPAGE_TEXT_TOP and MUI_UNCONFIRMPAGE_TEXT_LOCATION). Someone would thought software as old as NSIS and on third major version would have covered that looong ago...